# Boostrap dropdown input

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 w-100 ">
   <label class="text-light mb-3">Select te course</label>
    <select class="custom-select w-100 p-2 " id="inputGroupSelect02" placeholder="">

       <option selected class="select">Select the course</option>
       <option value="1">One</option>
       <option value="2">Two</option>
       <option value="3">Three</option> 
   
    </select>
         
</div>
```

Hi guys, I just made an online learning website and added some features. one of the features is bootstrap dropdown input. it looks fine on computer and tablet screen, however on mobile screen half the placeholder disappears. this is the code

Comment: I tested your code on Galaxy S8, Galaxy S9, Galaxy S20, iPhone XR, iPhone SE and iPhone 12 Pro. It works exactly the same on all mobile phones as in the computer browser. So, it would be useful to mention the model of your mobile phone, as well as the browser you use in it. You can also provide us with a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I tried to open my website on the messanger app i.e Facebook browser. Yesterday, right after you replied I copied and pasted my link in Google and it was fine. Do you know how to fix that Messanger/Facebook problem?

Comment: Nice. The rendering issue is one of numerous known problems with Facebook's integrated browser. Facebook argues that by eliminating the need to switch to a full browser, it enhances the user experience, however, as you can see, it degrades it. In some cases, the problem is the result of having mixed content. Namely, you may be providing your page through https protocol (with an SSL certificate), yet some of the contents may still be provided via http protocol. Can you confirm that all your contents (including bootstrap’s imported files) are served over the https protocol?

Comment: How can I do that? I mean confirming that all my contents are served over the https protocol?

Comment: One method is to examine the code of your page and see if there are any references to resources that begin with "http".

Comment: My website is deployed on Github, so I guess it does not have the https protocol.

Comment: Do you mean on github.io?

Comment: Yes, I upload my pages on Github.io

Comment: In this case, you should follow the steps provided in this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https). Pay special attention to the chapters "Enforcing HTTPS for your GitHub Pages site" and "Resolving mixed content concerns."